# Changin DIV background color with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have two DIV, and i want to change DIV color to green when its clicked (its working). Im counting the clicks on div, and i want to stop counting if the DIV is already green.

```js
var counter = 0;
$(function() {
  $(".tile").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(250,0,0)') {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#008000');
      counter++;
      $(this).append("/" + counter);
    } else {
      alert("Already colored!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 90vh;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 0, 0);
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tile'></div>
<div class='tile'></div>
```

So, if the background is red `(250,0,0)` then recolor the div to green and change div text to 1. But if the div is not red (so already colored), and if i clicked on the green div then show the alert message. Any ideas how can I fix that? I guess with my IF is wrong.

Comment: If you `console.log($(this).css('background-color'))` you'll see the value has spaces in it: `rgb(250, 0, 0)`

Comment: I would not rely on the `rgb` string to be consistent among different engines. Adding a class on click would probably be a safer alternative.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan edited, but still do nothing. any other tip?

Comment: Where did you add it? It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/01jvwf13/. Although I agree with @KilianStinson that the format of the RGB string is not very reliable and I'd use a class to colour the elements instead.

Comment: You should be able to do it with $(this).css('background-color','#FFEEFF'); => $(item).css('property','value');

Comment: Okay thakns, in JSFiddle working, but in my PhPstorm dont, its lol :D Nvm, i will change the RBG to class coloros, thank u everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS classes when you want to add/remove styling:

CSS

```
.red-bg
{
   background-color: red;
}

.green-bg
{
   background-color: green;
}
```

Javascript

```
if ($(this).hasClass('red-bg'))
{
    $(this).removeClass('red-bg')
           .addClass('green-bg');
}
```

Comment: You can do `toggleClass('red-bg green-bg')`